# Composer Github private repository not working with given key

Tags: php, github, ssh, composer-php, ssh-keys

I was trying to get a private repository from Github installed via `composer`. My `composer` configuration is as below:

```
"repositories": [
            {
                "type": "vcs",
                "url":  "git@github.com:{user}/{repo}.git",
                "options": {
                    "ssh2": {
                        "user": "ranacseruet" 
                        "privkey_file": "./keys/id_rsa",
                        "pubkey_file": "./keys/id_rsa.pub"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

However, it doesn't work with this configuration. It's still asking for github user/pass. However, if my system's github authorization is set up properly with keys, only then it works automatically.

In any way, composer configuration isn't working. Is anybody else facing the same issue or is there anything I did wrong/need to check here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you try keeping the full path for privkey_file and pubkey_file

Comment: Hello Hari, yes, I tried that as well. But same result. I am not sure but may be there could be some problem with my ssh2 installation. I will check on that.

Comment: Another article probably can help http://seld.be/notes/authentication-management-in-composer

Comment: i have similar problem: for me `git` from command line works perfectly with the remote repo (and I have keys in `.ssh/id_rsa`), however when I try to specify repo in `composer.json` (without explicit keys) it still asks for passwrod.

Comment: You seem to be specifying the same file for both public and private key. Is it possible that one of those should have a different filename? In my case those keys are in two separate files.

Comment: @LarryBorsato , hi thanks for noticing that. I have corrected it on the question. Just to confirm, it didn't made a difference, still doesn't work.

Comment: @Rana have you configured your github repo to use that key? It seems not to recognize that key.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but you could solve it another way using an [ssh config file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/).

This allows you to configure SSH connections to use specific credentials for 'virtual' hosts, which thus allows you to alter the way you connect to Git repos, and therefore can be used to modify Composer dependencies which use ssh.

Edit ~/.ssh/config e.g.

```
Host ranacseruet_github.com
User git
HostName github.com
IdentityFile [path-to]/keys/id_rsa
```

Then modify your composer.json to use the fake host and remove the ssh options:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@ranacseruet_github.com:{user}/{repo}.git",
    }
]
```

So when ssh tries to connect to the 'virtual' host ranacseruet_github.com, it will use the credentials specified.

I use this technique to define git remotes which need specific credentials. It should work exactly the same via composer, as it is a more general solution at the ssh-level.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, instead of passing just a plain repo URL like this `git@github.com:{user}/{repo}.git`, I needed to add `ssh://` prefix. So it ended to look like this: `ssh://git@github.com:{user}/{repo}.git`. Then it worked.

I didn't need to give a path for the private key. That was grabbed from the `.ssh` folder.

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "ssh://git@github.com:{user}/{repo}.git",
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63826284/14568628) of kkochanski (Sorry, i have not enough reputation to comment his answer):

His solution didn't work for me. I had to use a slash instead of a colon:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://git@github.com/[user]/[repo].git"
    }
],
```